# cloudinary error: must supply api-key - /node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils.js:982

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary to upload photos on my webpage.
I have added a new function to the webpage ( facebook login) and now the cloudinary throw an error when I try to upload a photo like before.

"/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils.js:982
        throw "Must supply api_key";
        ^
Must supply api_key"

The API_KEY, API_SECRET and the CLOUD_NAME are saved in a .env file, and these are correct.

```js
var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router();
var Campground = require("../models/campground");
var middleware = require('../middleware') ;          //because of the index.js default name
var geocoder = require('geocoder');

///////////////////////////////////////
// MULTER

var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});
var imageFilter = function (req, file, cb) {
    // accept image files only
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)) {
        return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
};
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFilter});

///////////////////////////////////////
//CLOUDINARY

var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME, 
  api_key: process.env.CLOUD_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_SECRET
});





router.post('/', middleware.isLoggedIn, upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
    //GEOCODER
    geocoder.geocode(req.body.location, function (err, data) {              
        
    //CLOUDINARY UPLOAD   
         cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(result) {           
                 var image = {
                     path: result.secure_url,
                     id: result.public_id
                 };
                 
                 
                 var name = req.body.name;
                 var price = req.body.price;
                 var description = req.body.description;
                 if(req.user.facebook.username) {
                     var username = req.user.facebook.username;
                 } else {
                     username = req.user.local.username;
                 }
                 var author = {
                    id: req.user._id,
                    username: username
                };
               if(!data.results[0]) {
                    var lat = 90;
                    var lng = 0;
                    var location = "North Pole";
                   
               } else {
                 lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                 lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                 location = data.results[0].formatted_address;
               }
                
                var newCampground = {name: name, price: price, image: image, description: description, author: author, location: location, lat: lat, lng: lng};
          //create      
            Campground.create(newCampground, function(err, result) {
             if(err) {
                 console.log(err);
             } else {
                 console.log(result);
                 res.redirect('/campgrounds');
             }
             
            });  
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<% include ../partials/header %>







    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Create a New CampGround</h1>
        <div style='width: 30%; margin: 30px auto;'>
            <form action='/campgrounds' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="name" type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name'>
                </div>
                 <div class='form-group'>
                     <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="price" type='number' name='price' placeholder='price' min="0.01" step="0.01">
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="image">Image</label>
                    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" required>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="description" type='text' name='description' placeholder='Write description'>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="location">Location</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Yosemite National Park, CA">
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary btn-block">Submit!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/campgrounds"> Go Back </a>
        </div>
        
    </div>






<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

Comment: "_API_KEY, API_SECRET and the CLOUD_NAME are saved in a .env file_" did you mean `CLOUD_KEY` & `CLOUD_SECRET` or is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean CLOUD_KEY & CLOUD_SECRET and CLOUD_NAME are saved in a .env file.

Answer (score 6):

The cloudinary config values must be in strings otherwise they won't work. 
Configure your code either of these ways in your cloudinary segment:

1a: **CloudinaryConfig.js:**

```
cloudinary.config({ 
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME, 
    api_key: process.env.CLOUD_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_SECRET
});
```

1b: **.env**

```
   CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME='sample'
   CLOUDINARY_API_KEY='874837483274837'
   CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET='a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1'
```

2:    Putting your cloudinary-supplied values directly into the code:

```
   cloudinary.config({ 
       cloud_name: 'sample', 
       api_key: '874837483274837',
       api_secret: 'a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1'
   });
```

**NOTE:** Ensure that you don't expose your config values for security reasons. If you're committing code to a public repo like github, use .gitignore to leave out whatever file where you store your secret info.

Checkout the cloudinary docs for more reference:  https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration.

Answer (score 2):

The reason can be your js file where you would have not included `require('dotenv').config();`
Try adding this and then run your code.

Answer (score 1):

The dotenv must be required up top where you are using your `process.env.API_KEY`:

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please format your code when you write an answer? I'll make even easier to read it for everyone!

Answer (score 1):

for common js files put :

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

for mjs files put:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```

in the same js/mjs file that you use:

```
 cloudinary.config({ 
        cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME, 
        api_key: process.env.CLOUD_KEY,
        api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_SECRET
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the API key directly in your code and see if that works. You could also add a print statement and see what response you get for API key

Comment: I logged to the console the API_Key and it was correct. It even didn't work when i put it directly in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a NodeJS server-side function to upload,
ensure you've installed the dotenv package;

```
yarn add dotenv
```

Thereafter, put the cloudinary variables in a '.env' file.
From the file (controller) where you're to make the upload, you must point to
dotenv, to that file, relative to where your package.json file is sitting. Here's an instance for me, trying to make an upload from 'CompanyControllers.ts'

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({path: "./backend/src/settings/controllers/CompanyControllers.ts"});
```

So, if I do;

```
console.log("\n\t Cloud name: ", process.env.CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_CLOUD_NAME)
.....my cloudinary cloud name is logged
```

```
const cloudinaryResponse = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(filePath, {
            cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_CLOUD_NAME, 
            api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_API_SECRET, 
            upload_preset: process.env.CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET_NAME,
            api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_API_KEY,
            resource_type: "image",
            secure: true
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.